# Can I create my own Ethereum network?

Tags: blockchain, ether, network

I'd like to fork Ethereum code (hypothetically) to create my independent Ethereum-like network (another world-like computer network with its own structure).

How can I reset or create new sets of ethers, so they can be mined from scratch at the original pace, so knowledge about existing discovered pools from the Ethereum network won't interfere in my new independent network?